# How to restrict access to certain URLs a specific port?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

My web configuration declares three connectors, http on port 8080 and https on ports 8081 and 8082.

In my servlet I want to restrict access to certain urls patterns to a specific port, e.g. a request to /Admin should be rejected unless it is on port 8082. This much is quite simple, I can check the port number in the service method of the servlet.

But I also need to be able to allow customer to change the ports. If a customer wants the Admin requests to be allowed only on port 9000 (instead of 8083) then this strategy fails.

One approach I can think of is to add an additional attribute to the connector in server.xml and access it in the servlet. Is this possible?

To elaborate, I want to add something like the following in `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="9000" connectorType="admin"....
```

And then somehow get programmatic to this in my servlet as follows. I realize `getConnectorProperties` is does not exist, this is just an example.

```
 if (request.getRequestURL().startsWith("/admin")) {
   String connectorType = request.getConnectionProperties().get("connectorType");
   if (! "admin".equals(connectorType)) {
     // return unauthorized
```

Any other suggestions for how I can address this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using different context roots (=apps) for the different ports. This shouldn't be done programmatically. Applications that accept different ports or protocols are configured in the `server.xml` with different `Service` components:

```
<Server>
    <!-- Define one Service for the open app -->
    <Service name="myOpenApp">
        <Connector port="8080"/>
        <Engine name="myOpenApp" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost"> <!-- default appBase is webapps -->
                <Context docBase="path/to/my/open/app"/>
                <!-- docBase is relative to appBase but may also refer an absolute path -->
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>

    <!-- and another for the restricted -->
    <Service name="onlyForAdmins">
        <Connector port="8081" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"/>
        <Connector port="8082" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"/>
        <Engine name="onlyForAdmins" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost"> <!-- default appBase is webapps -->
                <Context docBase="path/to/admins/only"/>
                <!-- docBase is relative to appBase but may also refer an absolute path -->
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Note that this is a minimalistic example.

If you need more complex URL patterns you can use `web.xml`s of the applications (`servlet-mappings` and such).

And basically, it isn't an authorization error... It's an unmapped URL. Your applications just don't support admin resources on non-SSL ports. So you'll get `404 page not found`.

Comment: What happens behind the scenes  ? Are we creating two instances in that case ?

Comment: Instance of what? There's still only one process. But two... Services :) . A Service binds Connectors to an Engine. You can further read in [their docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/service.html)